# Create JSON Object from Class in Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm pretty new to iOS development and Swift (so please bear with me).  I have a class object defined like this:

```
class LocationPoint {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
    var orientation: Double

    init(x: Double, y: Double, orientation: Double) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.orientation = orientation
    }
}
```

In my delegate, I create an instance of the class and append it to an array (declared outside the delegate):

```
var pt = LocationPoint(x: position.x, y: position.y, orientation: position.orientation)
self.LocationPoints.append(pt)
```

So far so good. I can show the array values in a textview object in my viewcontroller and it is definitely adding values each time it updates.

Now, what I'd like to do is after the array count reaches a limit (say 100 values) then package it up as a JSON object and send it to a webserver using a HTPP Request.  My initial thoughts were to use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) and [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to help with this...but if I try to break the problem down into smaller parts then I need to:

1. Create JSON object from array of LocationPoints
2. Create HTTP request to send JSON packet to a webserver

Right now, I'm just trying to solve step 1, but can't seem to get started.  I've used CocoaPods to install both pods (SwiftyJSON and Alamofire) but I don't know how to actually use them in my viewcontroller.swift file.  Can anyone provide some guidance on how to create a JSON object from a custom class structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look over `[NSJSONSerialization]` class [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html).

```
class LocationPoint {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
    var orientation: Double

    init(x: Double, y: Double, orientation: Double) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.orientation = orientation
    }
}

func locationPointToDictionary(locationPoint: LocationPoint) -> [String: NSNumber] {
    return [
        "x": NSNumber(double: locationPoint.x),
        "y": NSNumber(double: locationPoint.y),
        "orientation": NSNumber(double: locationPoint.orientation)
    ]
}

var locationPoint = LocationPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, orientation: 1.0)
var dictPoint = locationPointToDictionary(locationPoint)

if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(dictPoint) {
    print("dictPoint is valid JSON")

    // Do your Alamofire requests

}
```

Comment: Would that be better than SwiftyJSON?  Does this method have any issues in Swift (as I've read JSON objects are harder to create in Swift than Objective-C)?

Comment: I don't think it matters which framework you'll use, `NSJSONSerialization` is the framework provided by Apple since iOS 5. It also won't matter if you use Swift or Obj-C. You should read the documentation, there are a few requirements for the object that you want to create a JSON from.

Comment: Ok. I've got the following: `var json = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(obj: LocationPoints, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: NSErrorPointer)`... the issue is the last parameter - the NSErrorPointer.  I have no idea what I should provide here.  Any help?

Comment: First of all make sure this line returns `true`. `NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(LocationPoints)`. If it's not returning true that means your obj is not conforming to the docs

Comment: The documentation says:
An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:

The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.

All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.

All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.

Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

Comment: Thanks Marius.  You're right... the LocationPoints array does not pass that test.  The function returns false.  So, is there a better method to use to package up my class into a JSON object?

Comment: Sure, you should create a `Dictionary` from your object

Comment: Do you mean I should use a Dictionary instead of an Array for the LocationPoints (which is of type LocationPoint).  Or, do you mean my class (LocationPoint) definition should change to contain a dictionary instead of single property values?

Comment: I've updated my answer, you should make a `Dictionary` out of `LocationPoint`, and then you can have an array of that dictionaries

Comment: Thanks Marius.  That worked (I get a dictPoint is valid JSON statement)!  However, I had a followup.  What if I wanted to extend my LocationPoint class to include a timestamp (formatted string) and a userID (also a string).  Right now, it appears that the dictionary is declared so that the key is a string and the value is a number.  Is it possible to have different value types?

Comment: You can create a dictionary of this type `[String: AnyObject]`

Comment: Ok. One last followup.  Basically, inside my if statement... I have a valid object which can be serialized into JSON, but I'm still running into issues as to what I should use for the NSErrorPointer.  I have the following: `var json = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictPoint, NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: NSErrorPointer)`  I'm not sure what I'm supposed to use as the last argument.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I haven't used `Alamofire`, but I'm pretty sure it takes a `Dictionary` as a parameter, so you could just pass the dictPoint as a parameter.
p.s that method returns a `NSData` from an object, it's `data` representation of `dictPoint`

Comment: As for how to use `NSErrorPointer`, you just create a `var error:NSError? = nil` and in the method you add it like this `&error`

Comment: I promise... last one.  The function you provided converts a single Location Point into a dictionary which I could then package up with Alamofire... but ideally I don't want to push data out that quickly (my updates are approx every second).  Instead, I'd like to create a collection of Location Points and if a limit is reached (100) then process the collection and then send it out.  But, I'm getting hung up on how to create a dictionary object for a collection (an array of Location Points).  Am I just missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

To add to Marius' answer, I modified the code a bit to convert a collection of Location Points into a valid JSON object.  The answer above works for a single point, but this function can be used to convert an array of points.

```
func locationPointsToDictionary(locationPoints: [LocationPoint]) -> [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
    var dictPoints: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = []
    for point in locationPoints{
        var dictPoint = [
            "x": NSNumber(double: point.x),
            "y": NSNumber(double: point.y),
            "orientation": NSNumber(double: point.orientation),
            "timestamp": NSString(string: point.timestamp)
        ]
        dictPoints.append(dictPoint)
    }
    return dictPoints
}
```

Then, in the code you can use it like this:

```
var pt = LocationPoint(x: position.x, y: position.y, orientation: position.orientation, timestamp: timeStamp)
self.LocationPoints.append(pt)

if LocationPoints.count == 100 {
    var dictPoints = locationPointsToDictionary(self.LocationPoints)
    if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(dictPoints) {
        println("dictPoint is valid JSON")

         // Do your Alamofire requests
    }
    //clear array of Location Points and start over
    LocationPoints = []
}
```

This should only package up the JSON object after there are 100 location points recorded.  Hope this helps.