# Unable to create valid JSON Object?

Tags: ios, json, validation, swift, post

I have been trying to create valid JSON objects and can't seem to do so. I've been looking at [Create JSON Object from Class in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202796/create-json-object-from-class-in-swift) as a reference and this person seemed to get his code to work. I have something very similar. Here is my attempt:

```
func parseExportDB() -> [Dictionary<NSString, AnyObject>]{

    var exportDict: [Dictionary<NSString, AnyObject>] = []

    for tuple in export {
        var dictObj = [
            "PhoneID": 123,
            "LocLabel": tuple[crosslocation] as NSString,
            "Latitude": 123,
            "Longitude": -123,
            "Time" : tuple[time] as NSString,
            "Heading" : tuple[heading] as NSString
        ]
        exportDict.append(dictObj)
    } 
    return exportDict
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
var exportList = database.parseExportDB()
exportData.sendJsonToServer(exportList)
```

And this is how I try to send my JSON has a POST request to my server:

```
func sendJsonToServer(ExportList: [Dictionary<NSString, AnyObject>]){

    if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(ExportList){
        println("Is NOT valid JSON.")
    }
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "<Server link here>")!)

    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?
    if let serializedData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(ExportList, options: nil, error: &err){
        println("Export List: \(ExportList)")
        if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(ExportList){
            println("Is not valid JSON again!")
        }
        else{
            println("Valid JSON!")
        }
        request.HTTPBody = serializedData
        println(request.HTTPBody)
    }
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    ...
}
```

The issue is when I call the first and second `if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(ExportList)` statement, both seem to say that `ExportList` is not valid JSON. I have no idea why. I have looked at the link above and have looked at lots of links and they have all said valid JSON should be in the format of an `NSArray` or NSDictionary`. Furthermore, I have looked at my data and seems like everything looks as it should. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: My mistake on the code above.. anyways if anyone could help me with this next portion that would be great.. so I am trying to make a HTTP POST request and after I perform the code above, I get to this portion where I want to send data to my server. Here is my attempt:

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Request: \(request)")

        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Body: \(strData)")
        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as! NSArray
        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if(err != nil) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
```

However, when I try to perform the line `var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as! NSArray`, my data term always returns nil and I'm not entirely sure why... any insight?

Comment: `isValidJSONObject()` returns ***true*** if the object is ***valid***. Your if-logic is the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is correct BUT for a little detail:

you do

```
if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(ExportList){
    println("Is NOT valid JSON.")
}
```

if is valid then show error???

that's wrong way round.. you miss a NOT

```
if !NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(ExportList){
    println("Is NOT valid JSON.")
}
```

Comment: Oh.. my mistake.. Thank you. I was  just wondering then, can you help me on the next portion of my code? I really don't see how I can make a POST request. I will include the code in my answer above.